# css animation not scrolling to right

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an image that is the same size as a div, I want the div to slide out of the image, but It dosen't work. here is my code:

```html
<html>
<img src ="http://hokuco.com/box.png">
<div class="wrapper">
   <form action="form.php" method="POST" id ="slideRight">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form> 
</div>
<style>
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 245px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
}

.wrapper:hover #slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
</html>
```

the div underneath the image should slide to the right, out of the image, but dosen't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the name of your ID selector.

Here's work slide:

```css
.wrapper {
  top: 5px;
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 245px;
  border: 1px solid #009AFD;
  background:##009AFD;
}
#slideRight {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #009AFD;
  transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover #slideRight {
  transition: 1s linear;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://hokuco.com/box.png">
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="form.php" method="POST" id="slideRight">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: but is there any way to make the div be under the image then slide out of the image on hover

Comment: sorry for late reply. d'you mean `under` or `below`' the image? (now's 6.01 am in my country :D)

Comment: oh nvm but how do you make a div under an image, like overlapping

Comment: good. let me try to give you another if possible. I update again :D

Comment: take a look at the updated answer :D . I made new style.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `id="slideRight"` to `id="slide"` in your html and it works